# How to find where was a Module or a Class defined or lastly opened/modified

Tags: ruby, class, module, metaprogramming

Is it possible to know where a `Module` or `Class` was initialized (created or just opened last time for modifications)?

For example, for a method it's possible to know the location of its definition using the `source_location`. Anything like that possible in Ruby 1.9 or may be only in Ruby 2.x?

Maybe something similar to the `alias_method_chain` possible to make a hook before the every Class / Module changes are made?

Comment: This is potentially an interesting question, but I think it needs to be fleshed out some.  You might consider providing some code and asking your question in the context of that code.

Comment: For example, I don't know where is this class came from, but I want to know. How do I do that, without grep? Maybe it's even anonymous class or module.

Comment: Dmitry, the problem is readers don't understand your question, myself included.  That's evidenced by the fact that, eight hours after you posted your question, there are no answers and mine is the only comment.  To generate interest in your question you must be more specific, preferably with an example and desired result.  If you chose to elaborate (I hope you do), please do so with an edit rather than a comment.